# What is the proper way to ask someone if we still meeting tomorrow?

Tags: expressions, idiomatic-language

I asked a friend to meet up in person. He said we can meet tomorrow.

What is the correct way to ask if he still going to come to the meeting?
Should I use:

- Is the meeting still on?
- Are we still going to meet up?

Is there another way to ask that question based on English language grammar?

Answer (score 6):

I'll come to the point straight. I guess it is about the still part which makes the proposition a reconfirmation and not a mere request.

1. I hope we are still meeting tomorrow as planned? (Formal & Humble)
2. I hope the meeting is still on? (Informal)
3. Is the meeting still on? (Informal)
4. Are we still catching up tomorrow? (Casual)
5. Is there any change of plans for tomorrow's meeting?
6. Hope the plan for tomorrow's meeting still holds good!

And one can go on.......

Answer (score 1):

Both ways you have presented are common and grammatically fine. You might also ask, in a less formal way, "Are we still good for tomorrow?". Your friend, remembering your previous plans, will understand.

Comment: But, especially when spoken by a non-native English speaker, the ambiguous "good for tomorrow" is apt to be confusing.  It makes more sense to simply ask "Are we still having a meeting tomorrow?", or some such.